SP 2019 - Distributed cache service is not configured on server(s)
I have been troubleshooting this error for quite some time now. AppFabric service is running, Cache Host shows up, but I still see this error in SP 2019. I am also seeing Event ID 6398 in Event Viewer. FYI this is a single server farm.
Current status:



I have read through countless blog posts, multiple posts on stackoverflow, etc. I found this one that an answer was to rebuild the farm: AppFabric unable to create a DataCache (LMTRepopulationJob FAILS)
Does this mean completely uninstall Sharepoint and AppFabric and start over from scratch?
Other resources I have tried:
https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2023/02/16/trending-issue-distributed-cache-problems-after-applying-january-2023-cu/
SharePoint 2019 Distributed Cache Service
https://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2014/04/sharepoint-event-id-2137-how-to-fix/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/851075/cachehostinfo-is-null-when-adding-a-2nd-distribute
